# Prefixing and Classing everything

Tags: html, css

Usually when i create some HTML template, i tend to prefix and class (or id) everything, This is my way of keeping the markup more readable, and also it makes styling a lot easier.

For example if create a template called `MyTemplate`, then i prefix all elements like this

```
<form id="mt-form-blue" class="mt-form">
    <input class="mt-input-large" type="text" />
    <input class="mt-input-small" type="text" />
</form>`
```

I've seen lots of HTML templates, where the creators make very little use of classes  and ids.
My question is why? Does using many classes and ids, have an impact on the browser performance? Does it have any dangerous side effects?

Comment: No it shouldn't affect performance. It just makes your CSS a bit more unruly if you are defining new styles for each and every element.

Comment: I don't know about performance, but a lot of boil plate out there are just a basic style guild style guide, so it set what a "p"aragraph should look like, instead of #someSpacificParagraph.  just my two cent.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector do impact performance, but how much it impact will depend on its complexity and what operators were used. Usually you won't notice such tnings, but there are plenty of researches for this matter on the web.

Regarding the use of selectors, listing only the basic three, the use of them depends on what is your intention, for example:

- tag name selector - When you want apply style to every element of this type
- class selector - when you want to reuse your style in more than one element
- ID selector - when you want to apply your style to only one element per document

Of course, their use is not limited for the list above but I believe it contains the most common use cases.